# Google Map Bound Calculation without Javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Do anybody know how the google map bound calculation can be done without using any UI element and Javascript.

I have set of points and different zoom level. I can probably add the screen size and I need to calculate the bounds for provided coordinate and zoom level. I am trying to do this in the plain C# code.

Please help.

Comment: cleaner solution would be to do it in javascript using api and maybe then ajax to comunicate with the server,...

Answer (score 0):

as for calculating bounds - you can do it easily by walking array of your coordinates and extend bounds rectangle if point falls out. First coord is a start. I don't familiar with C# but there is the algo using pseudocode:

```
points = Array of coord(lat, lng)
bounds = object {
  top: null
  left: null
  right: null
  bottom: null

  function extend(coord: (lat, lng))
  {
    if (this.top == null) // empty
    {
      this.top = coord.lat; this.bottom = coord.lat;
      this.left = coord.lng; this.right = coord.lng;
    }
    else
    {
       if (coord.lng < this.left) this.left = coord.lng;
       if (coord.lat < this.bottom) this.bottom = coord.lat;
       if (coord.lng > this.right) this.right = coord.lng;
       if (coord.lat > this.top) this.top = coord.lat;
    }
  }
}
```

But of course much simplier way is to use already written google functionality.
Zoom level can be calculated somehow from the size of bounding box (for example you can find a table with rates in km or miles per pixel, or approximate width or map), but most comfortable way is map.fitBounds(bounds)